# What software takes high resolution WebCam photos?

Tags: software-rec, webcam, recording

Why is good webcam recording software so hard to find?

I need a program that will take high quality photos with my webcam.
Most webcam software I found is ridiculously cheap/old and ugly to interact with.

I tried using movie maker, but it will only record video at 640x480. I need to take a few photos at 2560x1920 (my webcam supports it @ 7fps).

I would screw it all and write my own Flash/Air application to do it, but I seriously don't have the time.

Please recommend a good program. I don't care if it costs money, as long as I can see a preview, set the high resolution, and take a high-quality photo.

Comment: Most webcams come with software that allows you to use the hardware to its fullest...are you sure that your webcam supports almost 5 megapixels? Nowadays I guess I have to ask but if it is an integrated webcam on a laptop, it most probably is not going ot have that sort of resolution...

Comment: @G19fanatic Yes, it is 5MP, and it came with just the drivers, it's this webcam: http://www.amazon.co.uk/TeckNet-Webcam-Camera-MegaPixel-microphone/dp/B000Q3VECE/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=computers&qid=1296650586&sr=8-1

Comment: I bet it's only interpolated software 5MP... But see my tool.

Answer (score 2):

[Cheese](http://projects.gnome.org/cheese/) is a good simple "photo booth" application for taking pictures with web cameras.

(If this answer doesn't work for you, please specify an OS.)

Comment: cheese is the solution i'd go with. Even if you need to try to use it with a livedisc, it'll work great (usually)

Comment: well, I'm mainly on windows7, but I do also have Ubuntu, so cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Logitech- Carl Zeiss Tessar 2.0/3.7. The resolution and quality of pictures this webcam produces is just ridiculous. Outstanding. I take my computer to places just to use my logitech webcam to take photos becuase its so fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux then QtCAM is a free software for taking pictures or videos with webcams or any USB cameras for that matter. This will give you the resolution and FPS that your webcams support.